# How can I pass data to a single task activity after the first time it loads

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an `Activity` that is a single task so I guess on create only gets called once. I want to pass some parameters from another activity. using Intent, i am putting extras but when I read them in the single activities `onResume`, the data is not there.

I need a way to pass data to a single task activity or restart it.

**edit**

To clarify. The problem is my activity uses Single Task as a launch mode in the manifest. I think this means oncreate only gets called once which is why i am trying to get the parameters in onResume.

When I resume my single task activit, I am unable to get any params added to the intent in the previousd activity because it does not start it but simply resume it

Comment: why are you using onResume to get the data and not onCreate? also post some code

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html This might be helpful.

Comment: onCreate() is called in many different cases.  You should learn about, and follow, the Activity life cycle documentation and not make guesses and assumptions.  If you always do the same tasks in onCreate(), onPause(), onResume() etc, then you don't care if it's a single task, a fragment or whatever.

Answer (score 6):

Use `onNewIntent()` with single-instance Activity. Calling `getIntent()` in `onResume()` for a single-instance Activity will return the Intent that originally started the Activity, not the Intent that the Activity just received. To ensure that `getIntent()` always returns the last-received Intent in a single-instance Activity, use `setIntent()` to store the last-received Intent.

This is documented in [the reference documentation for onNewIntent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29)

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to pass data to an activity that was started with `single task` and the activity is currently up then you need to override `onNewIntent` when a new intent comes into that activity this is where it goes

Answer (score 1):

you can start your second activity with `startActivityForResult` and pass the values that you want as the result from the second activity like this:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("result",result);
setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);     
finish();
```

then in the previous activity `onActivityResult` will get called and you can get the returned values like this:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if (requestCode == 1) {
     if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){      
         String result=data.getStringExtra("result");          
     }
     if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {    
         //Write your code if there's no result
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to start your other activity by `startActivityForResult`. If the activity is started simply by `startActivity`, the function `onActivityResult` wont be triggered.